# iOS app doesn't resume after unlocking screen

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

Generally with any app, if i open the app and lock the screen and after an hour or so if i unlock the screen the app re-launches. But my app fails to re-launch or resume. Is there any settings to resume my app or am i missing something?

```
if (!oprationQueue) {// Application did enter in background method
        oprationQueue = [[NSOperationQueue alloc]  init];
    }
    NSInteger updateSec = [[NH_Fetch_settings alloc] getUpdateTimeInterva];
    bgdataUpdateTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:updateSec target:self selector:@selector(updateData:) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
    NSInteger cleanSec = [[NH_Fetch_settings alloc] cleanupFrequency];
    bgCleanupTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:cleanSec target:self selector:@selector(cleapAllData:) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];

    [NH_advertisement sharedInstance].isFirstTime = NO;
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:YES forKey:@"advFirst"];


    backgroundTask_dataUpdate =[[UIApplication sharedApplication] beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:^{

        NSLog(@"%f",[UIApplication sharedApplication].backgroundTimeRemaining);
    }];

    backgroundTask_cleanUp =[[UIApplication sharedApplication] beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:^{

        NSLog(@"%f",[UIApplication sharedApplication].backgroundTimeRemaining);

    }];    
}

- (void)applicationWillEnterForeground:(UIApplication *)application{
    [application endBackgroundTask:backgroundTask_dataUpdate];
    backgroundTask_dataUpdate = UIBackgroundTaskInvalid;
    [application endBackgroundTask:backgroundTask_cleanUp];
    backgroundTask_cleanUp = UIBackgroundTaskInvalid;

}
```

The app doesn't throw the resume event after unlocking the screen.
This Come on log screen

**UIApplication _handleNonLaunchSpecificActions:forScene:withTransitionContext:completion:] ** unhandled action ->  {
    handler = remote;
    info =  {
        (1) = 5;
    };
}**

Comment: Please make sure that you have enabled `Background Modes` in `Capabilities` Tab of your app target.

Comment: Sir, I am sure that i enabled the background mode in capabilities

Comment: You have initialise `NSOperationQueue` but didn't use...why?

Comment: I have used that in  selector methods of timers....

Comment: I download the data every 10 min in background

Answer (score 0):

You can do what you ask for by following methods of `AppDelgate`

```
- (void)applicationWillResignActive:(UIApplication *)application;
- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application;
- (void)applicationWillEnterForeground:(UIApplication *)application;
- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application;
```

Do code in required method.

EDIT:

As you said that your app is not resuming or re-launching after unlocking iphone.

First thing re-launching means that `AppDelegate`'s `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` is called but in your case (after unlocking device this method is not going to called i.e. app is not going to relaunched in this case).

To resume app's task you can code in `applicationWillEnterForeground:` or `applicationDidBecomeActive:` and you written correctly.

Comment: I already written the code in all App delegate method.. but my application not resume after unlocking the screen... :(  help me

Comment: dear comments all code in background method(Above code) then try the same scenario. then you will identify whats exactly problem.if your work normally then problem is the your code.

Comment: What do you Means sir? @Hitesh

Comment: This Come on Log Screen...... UIApplication _handleNonLaunchSpecificActions:forScene:withTransitionContext:completion:] ** unhandled action -> <FBSSceneSnapshotAction: 0x164cc3d0> {
    handler = remote;
    info = <BSSettings: 0x16469150> {
        (1) = 5;
    };
}

Answer (score 0):

When you have lock device might be execute some code that may cause crash your application. Please follow simple step that have used to identify crash if any have during lock the screen. Try looking at any crash logs left on the device by your app.

```
Connect your device
Open XCode
Go to the Organizer (Window > Organizer)
Expand your device listing in the sidebar and select Device Logs
Look for any crash logs left behind by your app
```

And also tell me do you have any code in following method.

```
- (void)applicationWillResignActive:(UIApplication *)application;
- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application;
- (void)applicationWillEnterForeground:(UIApplication *)application;
- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application;
```

Comment: This come on log screen      ........ UIApplication _handleNonLaunchSpecificActions:forScene:withTransitionContext:completion:] ** unhandled action -> <FBSSceneSnapshotAction: 0x164cc3d0> {
    handler = remote;
    info = <BSSettings: 0x16469150> {
        (1) = 5;
    };
}

Comment: that means you have try to access private methods but the instance of this class doesn't exist.

Comment: and other possible reason is ......
 Apple recommends against using the underscore prefix on method names (they reserve that for themselves as a convention for private methods), but they don't have any such recommendation about instance variable names

Answer (score 0):

I think you should add below-mentioned code within beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler: ^{} method.

```
[application endBackgroundTask:backgroundTask_dataUpdate];
backgroundTask_dataUpdate = UIBackgroundTaskInvalid;
```

So the code should look something like this.

```
backgroundTask_dataUpdate =[[UIApplication sharedApplication] beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:^{

[application endBackgroundTask:backgroundTask_dataUpdate];
backgroundTask_dataUpdate = UIBackgroundTaskInvalid;

NSLog(@"%f",[UIApplication sharedApplication].backgroundTimeRemaining);
}];
```

Note: Every call to beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler  must have a call to endBackgroundTask, else the OS may kill your app.

Comment: UIApplication _handleNonLaunchSpecificActions:forScene:withTransitionContext:completion:] ** unhandled action -> <FBSSceneSnapshotAction: 0x164cc3d0> {
    handler = remote;
    info = <BSSettings: 0x16469150> {
        (1) = 5;
    };
}

Comment: This come on Log Screen